# Restructure duplicate csv indexes conditionally

Tags: excel, csv, excel-formula

I have a csv file that has husband and wife under the same section if there's a husband or spouse for this specific column, and multiple date of birth columns for when there are. Is there a way I can restructure this so that There's an individual column for each spouse, copying name to phone, (grabbing the individual first names if possible), and creating a new row with the individual data from date of birth to PD while removing the extra columns from the first?

I have no experience in excel or csv files to know how to do this, but I was hoping I could check with you guys and see if you're able to format this properly:

[image: Here's some example data of what I'm talking about]

Here's a link to some dummy data: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OGRY0JpMvhVFFEGzdSJwBtYqKXxN-uNO/view?usp=sharing

I would love to know if there's any way to do this, and if so how I can do it for multiple pages of thousands of clients

Answer (score 1):

This data clean-up can easily be done with Power Query (Get & Transform) in the Data ribbon. There different approaches to arrive at your desired result, but I would use the following:

- Load the table with all columns into Power Query and call it QHusband
- remove the columns with the **wife** data
- remove rows with blanks in column DOB: that leaves just husband data
- split the first name column by the & delimiter
- remove the column with the wife name
- save the query as a connection, do not load into the grid.

Now you have a query that returns just the **husband** data. Next,

- Load the table with all columns again into Power Query as QWife
- remove the columns with the **husband** data
- remove rows with blanks in column DOB; that leaves just the wife data
- split the first name column by the & delimiter
- remove the column with the husband name
- save the query as a connection only, do not load into the grid.

Now you have a query that returns just the **wife** data.

Create a new query that appends the two queries. Load that combined query into the spreadsheet as a table.

When you get new data, you can simply refresh the query

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.